# Laravel 5.5 read a file from the local disk

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, laravel-request, laravel-filesystem

I am trying to import a csv file with Laravel 5.5 from the local file location. For some reason it can't find the file on my computer however the path is correct.

```
$fileLocation = $request->file('file')->store('csv');
$importFile = File::file(storage_path('app/' . $fileLocation));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Storage` facade for this. Here is an example:

```
if (Storage::disk($disk)->exists($filename)) {
    return Storage::disk($disk)->get($filename);
}

throw new FileNotFoundException(sprintf('File not found: %s', $filename), 404);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't wanna use `Storage` facade, you can use below code to get the file

```
$importFile = Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::get(storage_path('app/' . $fileLocation));
```

but when you store a file with csv as store argument, it will save in `storage/csv` folder, and you just need call `storage_path($fileLocation)`.

be sure that your storage path is correct and for more information read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-uploads)

Comment: File::get doesn't seem to be available in 5.5

Comment: Works file on my side. It's available in Laravel 5.6.

Comment: Do I need to have a use keyword for it? what's the namespace for File, cause I get the following when I use File::get() in Laravel 5.5:
"Class 'App\Console\Commands\File' not found"

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's 5 years late, I wanna answer the question.

I have faced the same issue and I couldn't retrieve a pdf file from my Storage.

after that, I recognized the path that I'm giving to the get function is wrong.

I was giving the wrong path the `get()` function like:

```
/app/public/book/example.pdf
```

the correct path is:

```
/public/book/example.pdf
```

so:

```
$filePath = '/public/book/example.pdf';
$file = Storage::get($filePath);
```

the `get()` method will return `null` if the file doesn't exist.

if `exist()` method will return `false` if the file doesn't exist.